# What are the fastest, most memory efficient, and most concise ways to calculate a 3d range of points

Tags: python, methods, 3d, range

I've worked with several projects using python 2.6 and 2.7 that calculate positions, locations, or vectors in 3d space, and I've seen different methods to calculate all the points between two coordinates. 
For example, I often see this type of construct, using either xrange or range, to find all the points in a 3 dimension box,

```
s = list()
for x in xrange(xmin,xmax):
    for y in xrange(ymin,ymax):
        for z in xrange(zmin,zmax):
            s.append((x,y,z))
```

So, what are the most memory efficient, most concise, and fastest methods to calculate or iterate over a 3d range of points?

(To clarify, that's 3 different methods, not one, and the order of the calculated points doesn't matter)

Comment: The fastest way is to use C of course.

Comment: This sounds like a code golf / poll type of question, so it's off-topic.

Comment: You have asked 6 questions here. Please ask one at a time.

Comment: What are you calculating? Are you looking for a list of objects withing a 3D shape? (I assume you are).

Answer (score 2):

The following is definitely more concise and memory efficient, and I would expect it to be faster than the for loop as well but I haven't tested:

```
from itertools import product

list(product(xrange(xmin, xmax), xrange(ymin, ymax), xrange(zmin, zmaz)))
```

You can save a few characters with map:

```
list(product(*map(xrange, [xmin, ymin, zmin], [xmax, ymax, zmax])))
```

Comment: or `[(x,y,z) for x in xrange(xmin,xmax) for y in xrange(ymin,ymax) for z in xrange(zmin,zmax)]` if you're not into the whole `import` thing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a KD-Tree?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree

Here's some posts I'd suggest you look at:

1. [Get points enclosed by a 3d polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153816/get-points-enclosed-by-a-3d-polygon)
2. [How can I test if a point lies within a 3d shape with its surface defined by a point cloud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054193/how-can-i-test-if-a-point-lies-within-a-3d-shape-with-its-surface-defined-by-a-po)
3. http://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/gaertner/miniball.html
4. http://erich.realtimerendering.com/ptinpoly/

They're not python, but the logic is the same.